# MariaDB 10.2 - SQL Dump of specific columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am aware of the `--where` condition while taking dump of table where we can give condition on rows. But I have a table of the size 15GB and have over 100 columns.I need a dump of few columns out of it, and I want to do this as scheduled job where I will take dump of few columns of the source DB and store it to another server for reporting purpose.I also tried `INTO OUTFILE` but It won't save output as `.sql` and as `INSERT statement`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view v_ip that contains only the columns you want, and then dump that view into a csv file.

```
select * from v_ip into outfile '/tmp/test.sql'
   fields terminated by ','
   enclosed by '"'
   lines terminated by '\n';
```

Importing should be done with "load data".